# UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera is covered by parent view objects

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating a window-based application in XCode 4 (I am using window-based because I like how the universal apps are organized), but I am having trouble with the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum. I tried stripping down the code as much as possible to avoid any external errors, but I want to have two views:

the parent view: threeeyesmain.h / m / xib

the sub view: threeeyescamera.h / m / xib

I will post the code I have so far below.

The main issue is, when I push the button to take a picture with the camera, it works and I can see the camera controls, and I can even take a picture with no problem. However, whatever objects that are in the parent view are covering the camera screen. (i.e. if I am pointing my camera over a picture of a flower, I can see the flower on the screen, but there are buttons and imageviews from the parent view overlayed on it. I hope that makes sense).

(Side note: The funny thing is, when I tried this before using a view based application, it seemed to work, but now using virtually the same code in a windows based application, I get these problems.)

Maybe I am just missing something really obvious. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

**threeeyesmain.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface threeeyesmain : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)switchtothreeeyescamera:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end
```

**threeeyesmain.m**

```
#import "threeeyesmain.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "threeeyescamera.h"


@implementation threeeyesmain

-(IBAction)switchtothreeeyescamera:(id)sender{

    threeeyescamera *mythreeeyescamera = [[threeeyescamera alloc]
                                                                  initWithNibName:@"threeeyescamera"
                                                                  bundle:nil];

    UIView *thecurrentView = nil; 
    thecurrentView = self.view;

    UIView *thenextView = nil;
    thenextView = mythreeeyescamera.view;
    thenextView.alpha = 0.0;

    [self.view addSubview:thenextView];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:thenextView];
    thenextView.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender {


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**threeeyescamera.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>


@interface threeeyescamera : UIViewController {

    UIImageView *SetPhotoImageView;
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
    UIButton *BackButton;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *SetPhotoImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *BackButton;

-(IBAction)setImage:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end
```

**threeeyescamera.m**

```
#import "threeeyescamera.h"


@implementation threeeyescamera
@synthesize imgPicker, SetPhotoImageView, BackButton;


-(IBAction)setImage:(id)sender{


    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

//  if((UIButton *) sender == ChoosePhoto) {
//      picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
//  } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
//  }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    UIView *theView = nil;
    theView = self.view;

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:theView];

    theView.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {

    SetPhotoImageView.image = img;

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSData *ImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.9);
    [prefs setObject:ImageData forKey:@"ImageSpaceMiddle"];
    [prefs synchronize];
    SetPhotoImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:ImageData];

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([prefs objectForKey:@"ImageSpaceMiddle"]) {

        NSData *imgData = [prefs objectForKey:@"ImageSpaceMiddle"];
        SetPhotoImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imgData];
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Check the frame for the camera view and try `bringsubviewToFront` if required

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewname];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys!

I added this to threeeyescamera.m but I think I am doing something wrong.

    -(IBAction)SetImage:(id)sender{
 
 
 UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 
 if((UIButton *) sender == ChoosePhoto) {
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
 } else {
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 }
 
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:picker.view];

 
}

I think need more hand-holding~

Comment: I also realized that I am adding the ImagePickerController as a modal view. Also, when I use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlmum, it shows up fine. It's just the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera that gets covered up.